# Want to keep spaces between words when encrypting in Java using Caesar Cipher

Tags: java, encryption

When typing a message (e.g. I love Java) the encrypted version comes out without the spaces. So if a input shift value to be 0, the output will be ilovejava, but I want to keep the spaces between the words.
Can you please help me and thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CaesarCipherHW
{
    public static final String Alphabet = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a message: "); //prompts the user to enter the message that will be encrypted/decrypted
        String message = sc.nextLine();
        message = message.toLowerCase(); //converts the message to lower case characters only

        System.out.println("Enter shift value (between 0-25): "); //prompts user to enter the value by which each character will be shifted
        int shift = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("1- Encrypt" +
                            "\n2- Decrypt" +
                            "\n3- Exit" +
                            "\nChoose your option: "); //ask user to choose what the program will execute

    }

     public static class CaesarCipher
    {
        String cipher(String message, int shift)
        {
            String encryptedMessage = ""; //variable to store encrypted message

            for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) //use for loop to go through all the letters in the
                                                        // message that are also contained in the alphabet variable
            {
                if (message.charAt(i) == ' ') continue;

                int charPos = Alphabet.indexOf(message.charAt(i)); //find index of each letter in the alphabet
                int encryptPos = (shift + charPos) % 26; //find which index of the Alphabet to use to encrypt the letter in the message

                if (encryptPos < 0)
                {
                    encryptPos = Alphabet.length() + encryptPos;
                }

                char replaceChar = Alphabet.charAt(encryptPos); //use encryptPos variable to replace each letter in the message

                encryptedMessage += replaceChar; //add the encrypted character to the variable that stores the encrypted string


            }

            return encryptedMessage;
        }
    }

    
}
```

Comment: just don't replace if the original is a " "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cypher implementation is explicitly skipping spaces:

```
if (message.charAt(i) == ' ') continue;
```

Instead of skipping them, you can reinsert them into the output:

```
if (message.charAt(i) == ' ') {
    encryptedMessage += ' ';
    continue;
}
```